# How can I handle an unprocessable entity error with mapbox matching api?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, mapbox-gl-js

I am using the Mapbox matching API to compute a driving route between coordinates.
My code mostly works fine.
If I select two coordinates that are near each other and in close enough proximity to a road, the API request returns a route connecting the two points.

```
  const { body } = await MapboxMatchingClient.getMatch(matchOptions).send()

  if (body.code !== 'Ok') {
    console.error('Matching failed!')
    console.error('error code: ' + body.code)
    if (body.message) {
      console.error(body.message)
    }
  }
```

My code can also capture some errors. For example, if I try to calculate a route involving one or more points that are too far from a road, there is a noMatch response.

[image]

However, if I try to route two points that are too far from each other, an error occurs and my code does not detect it. Why not? And how can I update the code to catch this error?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was put my API call in a try catch clause.

```
  try {
    const { body } = await MapboxMatchingClient.getMatch(
      matchOptions,
    ).send()

    if (body.code !== 'Ok') {
      console.error('Matching failed!')
      console.error('error code: ' + body.code)
      if (body.message) {
        console.error(body.message)
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.statusCode === 422) {
      Vue.prototype.$notification.error({
        message: 'Failed to calculate route',
        description: error.message,
      })
    }
  }
```